# Como aplicar console.log no angular?

Tags: angular, console

Quero aplicar console.log no método angular, mas estou tendo dificuldade, estou fazendo assim;

```js
export class CervejaService {

    cervejasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/cervejas';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
            JSON.stringify(cerveja), { headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.json());
            });
    }
}
```

Mas está gerando esse erro;

> ERROR in src/app/cevejas/cerveja.service.ts(15,9): error TS2322: Type
>   'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.   Type
>   'void' is not assignable to type 'Cerveja'.

Como faço para aplicar o **console.log**?

Do jeito que ele está aqui ele funciona perfeitamente, e está salvando

```
adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
        JSON.stringify(cerveja),  { headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>  response.json());
  }
```

Eu só gostaria de saber aplicar o console.log no método.

Comment: Seu erro não tem nada a ver com o console, leia bem sua mensagem de erro `Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.`  e verifique se o método como está chamando o `http.post()` está correto. Dependendo da versão e do módulo que você está utilizando a chamada é diferente.

Comment: está correto sim, poderia por favor dá uma olhada na minha postagem, pois acabei de atualizar.

Comment: Poderia tentar assim: `then(response => {
                console.log(response.json()); return response.json();
            });` verifiquei que `Uma arrow function vazia retorna undefined` talvez isso seja o problema. Mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @Everson calma que vou tentar

Comment: @Everson pegou, é assim mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigado, poste sua resposta para eu marcar como certa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu retorno está incorreto.

Veja que você deveria esta retornando uma `Promise` do tipo `Cerveja`, mas você está retornando o tipo `void`

```
adicionar(cerveja: Cerveja): Promise<Cerveja> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.cervejasUrl,
            JSON.stringify(cerveja), { headers })
            .toPromise()
            .map(cerveja => {
              console.log(cerveja);
              return cerveja;
            })
    }
```

Provavelmente você quer remover o trecho `then`, e chama-lo no seu componente

Comment: Não @André, eu não quero remover o then, se você observar com atenção minha postagem o método adicionar está funcionando perfeitamente, o meu projeto está conseguindo salvar minha entidade cerveja, o que exatamente quero fazer é saber como aplicar o console.log no método para eu poder ver os dados inseridos no console do navegador, conseguiu entender agora?, se não entendeu eu posso tentar explicar de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Entendi, @wladyband. Mas me parece errado fazer o subscribe no própio service, pois você está perdendo os beneficios das Observables/Promises. Com a solução proposta, você verá que a sua IDE fará o intelissense de maneira incorreta, pois você terá um objeto do tipo `Cerveja`, e não uma `Promise` do tipo `Cerveja`. A maneira adequada de fazer isso seria usando o método `map` e ainda assim fazer o `then` no componente

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo com o uso do operador `map`